# Using Jquery UI Autocomplet with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery-ui, model-view-controller, autocomplete

I am trying to use the jquery autocomplete widget with codeigniter and keep getting an Internal Server error 500. Here is the code I am using:

View:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="customer_name"/>
  <script>

$(document).on('ready', function(){
    $("#customer_name").autocomplete({
        source: "<?=base_url('customer/customerLookup')?>" 
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
<?php



class customer extends CI_Controller {


public function customerInfo() {

    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('customer_view');
    $this->load->view('footer');

}

function customerLookup()
{


          $q = strtolower( $this->input->get('term'));
          $this->customer_model->get_customers($q);

 }

}
```

Model:

```
class customer_model extends CI_MODEL {


 function get_customers($q)
 {

    $this->db->select('customer_name');
    $this->db->like('customer_name', $q);
    $query = $this->db->get('customers');

        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
              foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
              {
                $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['customer_name'])); //build an array
              }

              return json_encode($row_set); //format the array into json data
        }
  }   
}
```

I have read through many forums and tried changing the 'enable_query_string' to TRUE also have tried 'uri_protocol'.

Theses are my current CSRF setting:

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
```

I continue to get the Internal server error and cannot figure out why. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't be echoing the response in the model class. Return the $row_set array from the model and echo it in the controller. Start there and let us know what happens.

Comment: @nullReference I tried changing that but still same result. It seems as if the get('term') is returning a null value. Here is what I am getting from my error logs:  PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get_customers() on null in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/prop/application/controllers/Customer.php

Comment: Your model should ``extends CI_Model`` & the first letter of your model filename & class definition should be capitalized

Comment: Try with `echo $this->customer_model->get_customers($q);` in controller.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are receiving is because you are not loading your model class into the controller. Without first loading the 'customer_model' the application does not know of it's existence, hints the null value error.

At the beginning of all of my controllers I made a habit of adding a constructor function and including all of the models/helpers/libraries that that controller is going to use within. To do this in your controller add the following code directly after your class declaration:

```
   function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('customer_model');

    }
```

Also make sure you are loading the 'database' library in:

```
$autoload['libraries']
```

of the autoload.php file

Comment: I am using autoload for all of my models so the model is definitely loading.

Comment: The error you are recieving: PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function get_customers() on null in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/prop/application/controllers/Customer.php...states otherwise

Comment: I still get the same PHP error even after I load the model in the construct function. I have it autoload in the autoload file and I am loading it in the construct like you did in this answer. Still same error. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you loading the 'database' library in the $autoload['libraries'] array? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230695/call-to-a-member-function-get-on-null-error

Comment: Yeah. So, I tried loading the model text in the controller and it works perfectly. You're right it's not loading the customer_model class and I have no idea why.