# How to use 'get' method with the where eloquent in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I was trying to get all the elements sharing a common row data 
but I keep getting this error I do not know why

> Call to a member function get() on null

Here is the code I used, I have imported the App\User and everything but still not getting it and I have a user in my table with that role_id

My controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Animal;
use App\Clinic;
use App\Role;
use App\Slaughter;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class ClinicController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()

    {

        $farms = User::where('role_id', 3);
        $user = Auth::user();
        $animal = Animal::all();
        return view('clinic.index', compact('user', 'animal', 'farms'));
    }
```

My user table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('address_id')->index();
            $table->unsignedInteger('role_id');
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('address_id')->references('id')->on('addresses');
        });
    }
```

But I am keep getting that error bellow I do not know the why

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to a member function get() on null error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230695/call-to-a-member-function-get-on-null-error)

Comment: There is no problem with my database

Comment: please put code of your controller function.

Comment: Are you sure that `User` is defined in your namespace? Your syntax is correct.

Comment: @EyadJaabo - If there was no `role_id`, it would give an SQLException

Comment: Your model are broken. Looks like you don't extends `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` or `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`

Comment: I have updated the question now

Comment: @Jimmyjbk I think your User Model does not extend with  `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`

Comment: That is true for it is the User laravel give when you run the auth command

Comment: What line is throwing this error for you? I don't see a get() call anywhere in the code that's been posted so far

Comment: Same as @AlecJoy, I can't even see a `get()` in your question. Please provide more code! We can't answer without the actual code that produce an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use App/User;

$farm = User::where('role_id', 3)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for getting the record

```
$farm = User::select(['id','name'])->where('role_id', 3)->get();
```

Comment: I have sorted it out

Comment: Great, Can you please explain how to sort it out?

Answer (score 0):

In case the User class extends Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model{}
```

calling

```
$builder = User::where('role_id', 3);
```

always returns an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder, therefore, calling

```
$user= User::where('role_id', 3)->get();
```

always returns a collection (which might be empty when there is no user with role_id = 3). Check the type of your User class.

Comment: But for me I have users with that rolr_id

Comment: The code you have posted as "My user table" is a migration. It is used for creating the table in the database. You need to create a model: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#defining-models

Comment: I do have a model too

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some missed steps that you didn't take.

The `User` does not refer to the table name but to the model class name.  So first things first you need to create a model.

In order to do that you use the command:

`php artisan make:model User`

If you want a dedicated Models folder(i always use one) you use

`php artisan make:model Models/User`

By that time you should have a model created but you need to set it up.

Going inside your `User.php` file you should have something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
 /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are NOT mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [
        'created_at', 'updated_at', 'password,
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        //
    ];
}
```

Now by including your model at the top of your file you can use your Model class.